# Pandas: read_csv with only HH:MM:SS in the index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I got this data:

```
Time;Flare;Praia;Spot2;Ruido
17:10:08.325;1.04;1.066;1.068;1.05
17:10:09.326;1.036;1.059;1.069;1.051
17:10:10.327;1.038;1.061;1.077;1.063
17:10:11.328;1.033;1.055;1.068;1.051
```

I read a file using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path + 'prueba.txt', sep=';',index_col=0,infer_datetime_format=True,
                       names=['time','flare','praia','spot','ruido'],header=1)
```

The result is

```
              flare  praia   spot  ruido
time                                    
17:10:09.326  1.036  1.059  1.069  1.051
17:10:10.327  1.038  1.061  1.077  1.063
17:10:11.328  1.033  1.055  1.068  1.051
17:10:12.329  1.041  1.057  1.075  1.049
```

You can notice that index-time have not dates (only HH:MM:SS) and the resulting index is not datetime-type.

```
type(df.index)
pandas.core.index.Index
```

I tried to use `pd.to_datetime` without success.
If I Have to add the date, how can do it?

Comment: What should the final result look like? Do you want `df` to have a DatetimeIndex? That's possible, but Pandas will fill in the missing date with the current date (by default). Or do you want a TimedeltaIndex? or...?

Comment: The initial data have not dates (only HHMMSS), When I read it appears like i showed, so in the final result it doesnt matter the date (if i can add it). I was thinking when using `infer_datetime_format=True` the index will be in a datetime-format (YYMMDD(today)  HHMMSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a DatetimeIndex, use `parse_dates=[0]`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data', sep=';',
                 names=['time','flare','praia','spot','ruido'], header=1,
                 index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
```

yields

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
                         flare  praia   spot  ruido
time                                               
2015-11-17 17:10:09.326  1.036  1.059  1.069  1.051
2015-11-17 17:10:10.327  1.038  1.061  1.077  1.063
2015-11-17 17:10:11.328  1.033  1.055  1.068  1.051

In [46]: df.index
Out[46]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2015-11-17 17:10:09.326000', '2015-11-17 17:10:10.327000',
               '2015-11-17 17:10:11.328000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'time', freq=None, tz=None)
```

Note that the current date is supplied by default.

---

To obtain a TimedeltaIndex, you could omit the `parse_dates` parameter and convert the HH:MM:SS strings later:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data', sep=';',
                 names=['time','flare','praia','spot','ruido'], header=1,
                 index_col=0)
df.index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df.index)
```

yields

```
In [54]: df
Out[54]: 
                 flare  praia   spot  ruido
17:10:09.326000  1.036  1.059  1.069  1.051
17:10:10.327000  1.038  1.061  1.077  1.063
17:10:11.328000  1.033  1.055  1.068  1.051

In [55]: df.index
Out[55]: TimedeltaIndex(['17:10:09.326000', '17:10:10.327000', '17:10:11.328000'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```